# Change author @id in JSON-LD schema generated by Yoast

Tags: wordpress, schema.org, json-ld, yoast

The Yoast plugin for WordPress generates Schema.org markup for posts. In my case it's something like this:

```json
"author":{"@id":"https://www.example.org/#/schema/person/123456abcdef"}
```

and

```json
{"@type":["Person"],"@id":"https://www.example.org/#/schema/person/123456abcdef","name":"John Doe","sameAs":[]}
```

How can I change the value of `@id` to a value defined by me? I've been using a manually generated `@id` for the same person on other pages and would like to use the same value here.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it in `wpseo_schema_person_user_id` filter.

Example: how to hide person id

```
add_filter( 'wpseo_schema_person_user_id', '__return_false' );
```

Tip: use PHPStorm with WordPress plugin to use autocomplete:

[image: PHPStorm WordPress autocomplete example]